# Display data from list in label Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qlabel

I have a list of data and the size of list is not fix. I want to display each item of this list in a label(Textview).

```
        self.valueT.append(value) 
        for i in self.valueT:
            // print(i)
            self.result.setText(i)
```

here in this code the `print(i)` work that display everything in console mean that it display the result but when I do `self.result.setText(i)` this one not working mean it did't display anything in the Label. and the second thing i want to display each value after 1sec. `self.valueT` is a list

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and be more specific on the other question, as it's not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A for-loop runs so fast that our slow brains can't pick it up, so you can't see the text. The idea of executing it every T seconds helps that this is not a problem but you do not have to use a for-loop but write it using a QTimer plus an iterator, that is, it is the same logic of iterating but using the timer events:

```py
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.label)

        self.resize(640, 480)

        listT = list("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")

        self.listT_iterator = iter(listT)

        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(timeout=self.on_timeout, interval=1000)
        self.timer.start()

        self.on_timeout()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_timeout(self):
        try:
            value = next(self.listT_iterator)
            self.label.setText(value)
        except StopIteration:
            self.timer.stop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: this is what i want. but I have still some problem. I modify the question will you look back to the question

Comment: @OsamaBillah 1) Take the time to understand my code. 2) Analyze your code if it is similar to mine, for example I don't see "listT_iterator" 3) unfortunately we will not solve a school assignment since that is your job